# Benchmark for concurrent/multi-threaded capabilities of the system

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking

Is anyone familiar and, if so, could you recommend me a benchmark for multi-threaded/concurrent capabilities of the system running JVM.

I wrote my own few years ago using acyclic barrier to track maximum number of threads and embarrassing parallelism.

I am interested in measuring differences in startup time, execution time and overall/maximal number of threads that JVM can sustain on different systems including HPC platforms running optimized JVMs. I am also interested in measuring performance on standard multi-threaded scenarios such as readers/writers and r/w access to shared data structure such as ConcurrentHashMap.

I wonder if there is something more official now focusing strictly on various concurrent scenarios that someone could recommend.

Thanks in advance.
(I am familiar with SPEC's JVM benchmark and DaCapo)

Comment: Can you add to your post what benchmarks this tool is supposed to output?  What does it measure?  Any examples of similar tools in other languages?

Comment: It is supposed to measure differences in startup time, execution time and overall/maximal number of threads that JVM can sustain on different systems including HPC platforms running optimized JVMs.